# synchronization mechanism in Java

Tags: java, synchronization

I need to make sure I understand synchronization mechanism in java, here are couple scenarios Id like to ask about:

1. theres a list 'a':
   List a

and there are two functions:

```
void foo(int i){
   synchronized(a){
      a.add(i);
   }
}
```

---

```
int goo(){
   return a.size();
}
```

---

If there are multiple threads running, and one of them uses synchronized code block in foo, can other threads at this time access goo (or more specifically, access 'a'?)? How about the opposite, if there is a thread accessing a at the momen through goo (which is unsynchronized), can a thread enter the synchronized block of foo? or is it going to wait on it?

2. Let there be:

```
void synchronized foo(){
   // do stuff
   notifyAll();
   //do stuff
   if(someStatement)
     return;
   wait();
   //do stuff
}
```

Some thread enters foo and reaches wait block, it releases the key of 'this', right? Second thread enters foo, and reaches notifyAll, at this point the first thread who was waiting should wake up and continue the code of foo, but it doesnt make sense because the other thread is currently holding the key. So what will happen?

3. Let there be:

```
class A implements Runnable {

Thread b;

foo(){
 b= new Thread(()-> { /*some lambda function*/};
 b.start();
}

goo(){
//here I'd like to notify the thread of b, how do I do it? 
}

}
```

What should I do if I want to notify a thread that I created with lambda function? this means I dont have a reference to it, but I do have a reference to object 'b'.

Thanks in advance.

This is me trying to learn java synchronization

Comment: 1. yes, (yes), yes, no. `goo` does not care about synchronization.

Comment: If you implement the `Runnable` interface, you shouldn't use the `Thread` class at all. Generally, extending the `Thread` class is something which should be avoided nowadays. For synchronisation there are several things in the [java.util.concurrent.* package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html).

Comment: @maio290 good to know, but right now im a student and in my assignment they expect me to use Thread class.

Comment: @luk2302 can you please be more specific about which questions you answered and how?

Comment: @Max Yeah, but it's normally either one of that: You usually don't mix Threads with any of the concurrent interfaces. That can make sense in some use cases, but I doubt that it does for your assignment. It's hard to help you here, you should probably start to try to solve the assignment (guess it's about developing stuff?) and ask for individual specific things you have trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. If there are multiple threads running, and one of them uses synchronized code block in foo, can other threads at this time access goo (or more specifically, access 'a'?)? How about the opposite, if there is a thread accessing a at the momen through goo (which is unsynchronized), can a thread enter the synchronized block of foo? or is it going to wait on it?

Yes, multiple threads can access those methods at the same time currently, either way round.

However, this is not correct code: you need to synchronize access to `a.size()` on `a` in order to ensure that you see any updates to the data structure that occurred in `goo`. For example, `foo` might see a size of `0` even after you have added something into the list using `foo`.

So, you need to make the code such that two threads can't be in those blocks at the same time.

Comment: you said - "For example, foo might see a size of 0 even after you have added something into the list using foo" . I assume you meant that goo will see 0. Why is that incorrect code? goo will see 0 only if it read the size before the modification happened, so it is correct up to that specific moment. What about the other questions?

Comment: *"goo will see 0 only if it read the size before the modification happened"*.  That is INCORRECT.  It may see 0 **after** the modification happened ... if there is no *happens before* relationship  from the write by one thread and the subsequent read by the second one.  It is counterintuitive.  But true.  Read Chapter 17.4 of the JLS.